# .htaccess - hiding subfolder1 in URL but showing subfolder2 (other website)

Tags: .htaccess, url, hide, subdirectory

I have a wordpress website physically located in the "wordpress" subfolder of the root folder of the website. I manage to hide the subfolder "wordpress" in the URL with the following code:

.htaccess on root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ wordpress/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wordpress/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess in wordpress subfolder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

However, I have another website in another subfolder let's call it "other-wp" and this needs to remain as it is, with the URL pointing to:
https://mywebsite.com/other-wp/

Since I managed to hide the "wordpress" folder in the URL, I am unable to acces my "other-wp" it says the page doesn't exist.

I'm not skilled with coding for .htaccess so i don't know what i need to do to fix it.

Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an exception for that second resource:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other-wp
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

I also made some other modifications to that top level configuration file, just smaller optimizations. In general you should check if you can place such global rules in the actual http server's host configuration. Using distributed configuration files (".htaccess") is just a fallback if you have no access to the real configuration. They work, but come with disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks Arkascha also for the optimisations. it would work if the physical directory was indeed /other-wp ma that's just the virtual directory. The physical directory is something like /sites/default/ and the other cms is drupal i dont know anything of. My mistake, i should have better explained...

Comment: I fail to see what difference that should make. If that "other cms" can be reached using the URL `/other-wp` then above rules will work.

Comment: i dont know either but as soon sas i add the 4^ line: (RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]) then the /other-wp stops opening the drupal website but gives a 404 error message as a wordpress page missing....

Comment: There must be some other factor involved, some other rewriting rules you did not mention until now... Please use a fresh anonymous browser window, open the network tab inside the browsers console, make a request to `/other-wp` and monitor the exact response you receive back. Just one response? Or do you see redirections?